# Change python app from mysql to sqlite

Tags: python, mysql, sqlite

I have a python app written for mysql I want to convert to use sqlite instead. The tables are created in a file called db.py. In simple terms I think I want to run something like

```
createDb = sqlite3.connect(':memory:'')
queryCurs = createDB.cursor()

conn = sqlite3.connect(r"db.py")
```

but I am unsure if this will have the result I expect, i.e., create the database as previously defined in mysql and allow the app function purely in memory.

Are my above statements correct or is there something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You cannot do what you want to do; sqlite cannot parse Python for you and 'understand' what your `db.py` script does with MySQL.

Your `db.py` script doesn't contain the MySQL tables either; it at most contains SQL statements that instruct MySQL to create those tables.

You'll have to translate those SQL statements to sqlite instead; each database brand uses their own dialect of SQL. It'll be similar but not the same, as MySQL and sqlite have different philosophies about how databases ought to store and treat data.

If you were using a ORM like SQLAlchemy, then you need to configure the ORM to connect to sqlite instead of MySQL; a good ORM can translate the table structures expressed in Python code to different database SQL dialects for you.

Comment: The major differences are that sqlite uses ? and :name instead of %s and %(name)s for parameter binding, and sqlite is weakly typed. Other than that, most code is straightforward to convert. But you do have to actually convert the code and run it; there's no way around that.